# Отправить post запрос на rest api контроллер

Tags: javascript, post, requests, asp

Нужно отправить POST запрос на `rest-api` контроллер и получить ответ с помощью скрипта в приложении `asp web forms`.  Скрипт :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function clientfunction() {
            try {
                var request = new XMLHttpRequest;
                request.onreadystatechenge = function () {
                    if (request.readyState == 4) {
                        console.log('.....');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        console.log('-----');
                    }
                }
                request.open("POST", "https://...", false);
                request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                request.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
              request.send("post data");
            } catch (err) { console.log(err); }
        }
</script>
```

В консоли выводится ошибка :

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

Странно что в постмане при указании того же url, метода, тех же заголовков и строки с телом запроса все проходит как положено - запрос уходит и я получаю корректный ответ. В чем проблема скрипта или дело в браузере?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
>
> > Странно что в постмане при указании того же url, метода, тех же заголовков и строки с телом запроса все проходит как положено - запрос уходит и я получаю корректный ответ.

Postman - тулза для девелопа, она по дифолту не проверяет, что происходит с *CORS*, браузер это уже проверяет.

> В чем проблема скрипта или дело в браузере?

Возможно вам стоит присмотреться к `fetch`.

```js
fetch(url, {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
    },
    body: 'foo=bar&lorem=ipsum'
  })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log('Request succeeded with JSON response', data);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Request failed', error);
  });
```

[Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

[Введение в fetch](https://habr.com/post/252941/)

Comment: Мне вот интересно как постман ухитряется отправить более 200  асинхронных запросов в сек в то время как простой код на js не больше 10?

Comment: @Сергей `Postman` - написан с использованием `Electron`, а там уже и `Nodejs` со своими аснихронными риквестами и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: `Nodejs` производительней обычного `javascript`?

Answer (score 0):

Думаю что сервер должен заниматься "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"

не думаю что это верно??   xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

это сервер вам должен разрешить запросы с другого домена??
т.е. если у вас бакэнд на www.qwe.by, клиент на www.asd.by, то сервер не даст разрешение на передачу никаких кроме текствых данных без "Access-Control-Allow"
Может как-то так?

```
    public class AllowCrossSiteJsonAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        StringValues all = "*";
        var ctx = filterContext.HttpContext;
        var origin = ctx.Request.Headers["Origin"];
        var allowOrigin = origin.Count > 0 ? origin : all; //err StringValues.IsNullOrEmpty(ctx3)
        ctx.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", allowOrigin);
        ctx.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
        ctx.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*");
        ctx.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "false");
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
public class ContentTypeAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        //("Content-Type", "application/xml;charset=UTF-8");
        //("Content-Type", "text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        //("Content-Type", "text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```